# Rename files (delete some characters that are not always the same)

Tags: shell, sed, filenames, rename

I have some files named like this :

```
DA1_ATGCATG_L001_R1.fastq.gz
Oeu43_TCATGAC_L004_R2.fastq.gz
```

I want to delete the part after the first "_" but keep the end of the names from "_R" to obtain this :

```
DA1_R1.fastq.gz
Oeu43_R2.fastq.gz
```

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/073

Answer (score 3):

In `bash` or POSIX `sh`:

```
for file in *.fastq.gz; do
    mv -- "$file" "${file%%_*}_${file##*_}"
done
```

Comment: (note that contrary to `zmv`, it will not check for potential conflicts, you may want to add a `-i`).

Answer (score 1):

With `zsh`:

```
autoload zmv # best in ~/.zshrc
zmv '(*)_*(_R*)' '$1$2'
```

Comment: +1 --`zmv` is a very handy utility -- I wish it was available separately from `zsh` for resource constrained environments, though.

Comment: @ChrisDown, it's nice because it can harness the full power of the zsh language. It's hardly more resource hungry than `perl`'s `rename` though. You can always have it separately with `#! /bin/zsh -` `autoload zmv; zmv "$@"`.

Comment: I was thinking more of storage constraints rather than runtime constraints -- I've wanted to use it on some devices with >=16M of storage before and had trouble justifying 700k just for zmv.

Comment: @ChrisDown, that's what I had in mind when comparing with perl's `rename`. On this system, the base zsh package takes 1.8MB and the base perl one 17MB. Note that if you only want zmv, you can trim down zsh to include only the modules you want (removing zle alone would save a lot).

Answer (score 1):

Using perl's `rename` (named `prename` in Ubuntu)

```
prename 's/^([^_]*).*(_R.*)/$1$2/' *.fastq.gz
```